# TypeError: activities.map is not a function eventhough mapping over an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following an online course and i am trying to find the reason of this problem for hours. It a React app with asp.net core api. Problem is in React side. It is simple React app for now. I worked with props.

***I pass down my state like this. App.tsx => ActivitiesDashboard => ActivitiesList***

***activities*** is a state initialised as empty Array as you can see below in App.tsx, it contains this Activity objects
type Activity

```
export interface Activity {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    date: Date;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    city: string;
    venue: string;
}
```

First here is **App.tsx** where everything starts.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Activity } from '../models/activity';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import ActivityDashboard from '../../features/activities/dashboard/ActivityDashboard';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

function App() {
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState<Activity[]>([]);
    const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] =
        useState<Activity | undefined>(undefined);
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get<Activity[]>('http://localhost:5000/api/activities')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setActivities(res.data);
                console.log('activities res.data => ', res.data);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleSelectActivity = (id: string) => {
        setSelectedActivity(activities.find((x) => x.id === id));
        console.log(selectedActivity);
        console.log(activities);
    };

    const handleCancelSelectActivity = () => {
        setSelectedActivity(undefined);
    };

    const handleFormOpen = (id: string) => {
        id ? handleSelectActivity(id) : handleCancelSelectActivity();
        setEditMode(true);
    };
    const handleFormClose = () => {
        setEditMode(false);
    };

    const handleCreateOrEditActivity = (activity: Activity) => {
        activity.id
            ? setActivities([
                  ...activities.filter((x: Activity) => x.id !== activity.id),
                  activity,
              ])
            : setActivities([...activities, { ...activity, id: uuid() }]);
        setEditMode(false);
        setSelectedActivity(activity);
    };
    const handleDeleteActivity = (id: string) => {
        setActivities({...activities.filter(x => x.id !== id)} );
    };

    return (
        <>
            <NavBar openForm={handleFormOpen as any} />
            <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
                <ActivityDashboard
                    activities={activities}
                    selectedActivity={selectedActivity}
                    selectActivity={handleSelectActivity}
                    cancelSelectActivity={handleCancelSelectActivity}
                    editMode={editMode}
                    openForm={handleFormOpen}
                    closeForm={handleFormClose}
                    createOrEdit={handleCreateOrEditActivity}
                    deleteActivity={handleDeleteActivity}
                />
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}
export default App;
```

and this is the response contains activities array of activity objects after setActivities(res.data) inside UseEffect.
[image: console.log(res.data) via activities state after useEffect]

here below is **ActivityDashboard.tsx** (the structure for activities is ***App.tsx => ActivityDashboard => ActivityList***)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Activity } from '../../../app/models/activity';
import ActivityDetails from '../details/ActivityDetails';
import ActivityForm from '../form/ActivityForm';
import ActivityList from './ActivityList';

interface Props {
    activities: Activity[];
    selectedActivity: Activity | undefined;
    selectActivity: (id: string) => void;
    cancelSelectActivity: () => void;
    editMode: boolean;
    openForm: (id: string) => void;
    closeForm: () => void;
    createOrEdit: (activity: Activity) => void;
    deleteActivity: (id: string) => void;
}

const ActivityDashboard = ({
    activities,
    selectedActivity,
    selectActivity,
    cancelSelectActivity,
    editMode,
    openForm,
    closeForm,
    createOrEdit,
    deleteActivity,
}: Props) => {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Column width="10">
                <ActivityList
                    activities={activities}
                    selectActivity={selectActivity}
                    deleteActivity={deleteActivity}
                />
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width="6">
                {selectedActivity && !editMode && (
                    <ActivityDetails
                        activity={selectedActivity}
                        cancelSelectActivity={cancelSelectActivity}
                        openForm={openForm}
                    />
                )}
                {editMode && (
                    <ActivityForm
                        closeForm={closeForm}
                        activity={selectedActivity}
                        createOrEdit={createOrEdit as any}
                    />
                )}
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
    );
};
export default ActivityDashboard;
```

Finally **ActivityList.tsx** where i get the error at activites.map is not a function

```
import { Button, Item, Label, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Activity } from '../../../app/models/activity';

interface Props {
    activities: Activity[];
    selectActivity: (id: string) => void;
    deleteActivity: (id: string) => void;
}
const ActivityList = ({
    activities,
    selectActivity,
    deleteActivity,
}: Props) => {
    return (
        <Segment>
            <Item.Group divided>
                {activities.map((activity) => (
                    <Item key={activity.id}>
                        <Item.Content>
                            <Item.Header as="a">{activity.title}</Item.Header>
                            <Item.Meta>{activity.date}</Item.Meta>
                            <Item.Description>
                                <div>{activity.description}</div>
                                <div>
                                    {activity.city}, {activity.venue}
                                </div>
                            </Item.Description>
                            <Item.Extra>
                                <Button
                                    floated="right"
                                    content="View"
                                    color="blue"
                                    onClick={() => selectActivity(activity.id)}
                                />
                                <Button
                                    floated="right"
                                    content="Delete"
                                    color="red"
                                    onClick={() => deleteActivity(activity.id)}
                                />
                                <Label basic content={activity.category} />
                            </Item.Extra>
                        </Item.Content>
                    </Item>
                ))}
            </Item.Group>
        </Segment>
    );
};
export default ActivityList;
```

In ActivitiesList when i trigger deleteActivity(activity.id), i get that error.[image: the error image]

It says TypeError activities.map is not a function.

I searched for this error and i know that map must be implemented upon an Array. **I initialized the activities state with empty array in App.tsx**. **i can see .map autocompletion in vscode**. I can not find the what causes this behavior. **I am trying to filter an array objects by filtering one incoming activity.id in handleDeleteActivity. But as i click to Delete i take that activities.map is not a function error.**

I am trying so hard to find the problem. In the Udemy Course i follow, there was not errors. My code is almost the same code. Please don't hesitate to ask me anything you need to see inside my code.

The repository of project is : https://github.com/ibrahimoguzhany/SocialAppCoreReact react app is inside client-app.

Comment: Your delete function changes activities to an object instead of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `setActivities({...activities.filter(x => x.id !== id)} );` you've accidentally set curly braces instead of square brackets. It creates an object with the array indexes as properties so it doesn't immediately fail, but it does when reaching the `.map` line. Just replace it with:

```
setActivities([ ...activities.filter(x => x.id !== id) ]);
```

Comment: I feel sorry that you had to write such a long question for this!

Comment: Yeah it was shocking to realise the difference between looking and seeing.I looked that setActivities Part at least 2 times and i even changed it from {...} to [...] it was my inattention. Thank you very much i feel better now :)

Comment: @forthecode you're welcome, glad I could help